# How to run intent and start a new class

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to pass the intent ANNO and after the class start TurniDB which is composed of a TabWidget, how can I do?

```
 public class Ins_anno extends Activity {
        Intent ANNO,TAB;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_anno);
            int i=2014;
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Gennaio.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Febbraio.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Marzo.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Aprile.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Maggio.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Giugno.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Luglio.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Agosto.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Settembre.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Ottobre.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Novembre.class);
            ANNO= new Intent(this, Dicembre.class);
            TAB= new Intent(this, TurniDB.class);

            String pkg=getPackageName(); 

            ANNO.putExtra(pkg+".myInt", i);{
                 {
                     startActivity(TAB);
                }}
        }
    }
```

this I need to pass the variable

private void displayData() {

```
Intent ANNO=getIntent(); // l'intent di questa activity
String pkg=getPackageName();


int i=ANNO.getIntExtra(pkg+".myInt", -1);   
System.out.println(""+i+"");
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anno_txt);  
tv.append("Gennaio  "+i+"\n");


dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.TURNI_TABLE+" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio' and ANNO = "+i+"", null);
```

Comment: You are overwriting your ANNO intent each time and only start your TAB intent

Comment: then changing the variable, I can select the year of interest to me to see

Comment: This is going to be a disaster man.. its like a very wrong way of using intents.. And please put your log.

Comment: You are missing out a few things, when do you actually want to start your TurniDB activity?

Answer (score -1):

```
int a;
a = 1;
a = 2;
a = 4;
```

Why are you doing things like that with your `Intent TAB` variable?

```
{{
   // code
}}
```

This is very useless and looks very bad, why you use the `{` and `}` there? Is there an exception being thrown? Can you place a logcat if there is an exception. Because you maybe forgot to edit your AndroidManifest.